# how to make PYQT4 app built with cx_Freeze on UBUNTU work on Linux SUSE.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, cx-freeze, suse

I am a little new to Linux, and I've currently made an app using **PYQT4**-**python3.4** using **cx_Freeze** on **Ubuntu**. It worked okay on Ubuntu, however, when i was trying to open the app on linux **SUSE** , it did not work.

the error i get is

> "Could not display AppName"
>
> There is no application installed for "executable" files.
>
> Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

I'm guessing that I need to make a new build for each linux distribution I want to run the app? or is there a better way to make my program portable for all linux environments using only one build?

Note: here is my setup.py that i run for cx_freeze(if at all this needs to be modified please let me know! :D )

```
import sys,platform
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

def getTargetName():
    myOS = platform.system()
    if myOS == 'Linux':
        return "AppName"
    elif myOS == 'Windows':
        return "AppName.exe"
    else:   
        return "AppName.dmg"


base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"
 
exe = Executable(script = "main.py", base=base, targetName = getTargetName())

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["re", "sip"],
                     "includes":["modules"],
                     "icon":"icon.ico"}

setup(  name = "setup",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "GUI Application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [exe])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you run it from a terminal, by cd-ing to that directory and running `./AppName`, does it work?

Comment: I tried "./AppName" and the terminal says command not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, all i was missing was to do a

```
chmod +x AppName
```

Then i ran it in terminal and it worked like a charm.
Also, i was able to double click the app and it ran too!